# Java Map implementation that returns a default value instead of null

Tags: java, default

I have a `Map<String, List<String>>` in my code, where I'd avoid potential null pointers if the map's `#get()` method returned an empty list instead of null. Is there anything like this in the java API? Should I just extend `HashMap`?

Comment: using the decorator pattern would probably be better than extending HashMap...

Comment: I don't doubt you, but why would it be better?

Comment: @jk: Why would you want to limit yourself to it *always* being a HashMap? What if sometimes you wanted a LinkedHashMap? Or a ConcurrentHashMap? Or a TreeMap? Basically, favour composition over inheritance :)

Comment: @Jon & @kem, I'm not too familiar with the decorator panel, as the examples are typically for GUI design, which I don't do. I'm guessing by @Jon's statement that a decorator will avoid binding to a particular implementation?

Comment: @jk: Yes. See my answer for a bit more detail.

Comment: Okay, I've researched and understand the decorator pattern now. Thanks. You should put this answer below so I can give credit!

Comment: @jk: @Jon's answer is an example of the decorator pattern.

Comment: @jk: I strongly recommend using a Guava `Multimap` as suggested by @Stephen C. I think this is what you really want, rather than a general purpose `Map` that returns a non-null value when it doesn't contain a key.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/guava-discuss/eVRHDBcgynA%5B1-25%5D

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519339/hashmap-to-return-default-value-for-non-found-keys

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[@Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4833375/139985) is a good way to do what you are asking directly.

But is strikes me that what you might be trying to implement is a "multimap"; i.e. a mapping from a key to a collection of values.  If that is the case, then you should also look at the multimap classes in Guava or Apache commons collections.

Look at:

- the [`com.google.common.collect.Multimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface and its implementations, or
- the [`org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) interface and its implementations.
- the [`org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html) interface and its implementations (a new version of the previous MultiMap; introduced in v4).

Comment: +1 And `get()` on a `Multimap` that doesn't contain the key returns an empty `Collection` by contract... exactly what the OP wants. The same isn't true of the Apache Commons `MultiMap` which has unspecified behavior.

Comment: @ColinD True. When using apache commons, we can use DefaultedMap, which returns a default value when the map does not contain the specified value.

Answer (score 40):

Thanks to `default` methods, Java 8 now has this built in with [`Map::getOrDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-):

```
Map<Integer, String> map = ...
map.put(1, "1");
System.out.println(map.getOrDefault(1, "2")); // "1"
System.out.println(map.getOrDefault(2, "2")); // "2"
```

Comment: This is the slimmest answer as it doesn't require Guava. And, by the way, it was what I was looking for. Upvoting.

Comment: Looks like based on timing this is the best solution, but came way late to the party (thanks java 8!). I like its simplicity. +1

Comment: Should be the accepted answer now that Java 8 is commonplace.

Comment: This is useful, but actually the OP asked for the map's `#get` method to return the value, not use another method. These things are not the same =)

Comment: This does not respond the original question - the OP wants to "avoid potential null pointers".  The implementation of `getOrDefault` is more or less like `if (get(key) != null) || containsKey(key)) return get(key) else return defaultValue;`. So if the map contains the key, but the value is `null`, you will not avoid the null pointer!

Answer (score 24):

As noted in comments:

> Guava's computing map concept was superseded with [`LoadingCache`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained). Also java 8 introduced to Map interface nice [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) default method which doesn't break map contract and features lazy evaluation .

---

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) had the idea of a "computing map" which will execute a function to provide a value if it's not present. It was implemented in `MapMaker.makeComputingMap`; you could now use `CacheBuilder` - see [`CacheBuilder.build`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#build-com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader-) for more details.

It may be overkill for what you're after - you might be better off just writing a `Map` implementation which *has* a `Map` (using composition rather than extending any particular implementation) and then just return the default if it's not present. Every method other than `get` could probably just delegate to the other map:

```
public class DefaultingMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>
{
    private final Map<K, V> map;
    private final V defaultValue;

    public DefaultingMap(Map<K, V> map, V defaultValue)
    {
        this.map = map;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    @Override public V get(Object key)
    {
        V ret = map.get(key);
        if (ret == null)
        {
            ret = defaultValue;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    @Override public int size()
    {
        return map.size();
    }

    // etc
}
```

Comment: Beware: doing only this breaks the contract for `get()`: that if the map doesn't contain the key, `null` is returned.  To be conformant you should override `containsKey()` to *always* return `true`.  I would assume `makeComputingMap()` would do that as well but didn't find it stated explicitly in the docs.

Comment: @Mark: Possibly. Although then you get into trickiness around iterating over the keys, as well... basically sooner or later the abstraction breaks. *Where* you break it would definitely be a matter for deep consideration :)

Comment: The `// etc` is not small, and makes this solution impractical IMO.

Comment: Alternately you could extend com.google.common.collect.ForwardingMap (from Google Guava) which makes the implementation @JonSkeet suggested much less verbose.

Comment: Guava's computing map concept was superseded with [LoadingCache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained). Also java 8 introduced to Map interface nice [computeIfAbsent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31234010/603516) default method which doesn't break map contract and features lazy evaluation

Comment: @Vadzim: Thanks, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: The link to Guava's `MapMaker.makeComputingMap` is dead

Comment: @naXa: Yes, for reasons that the start of the answer explains. I've updated the links a bit more though.

Answer (score 11):

Similar to previous posts except you can just override the get method if you want to change its behaviour.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>() {
    public String get(Object key) {
        List<String> list = super.get(key);
        if (list == null && key instanceof String)
           super.put(key, list = new ArrayList<String>());
        return list;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Guava has a method to do exactly what you want. It is similar to [Argote's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4833378/9636).

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = ...
Functions.forMap(myMap, Arrays.asList("default", "value"));
```

Comment: Very nice one-liner. :D

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how does this create a `Map` implementation that has a default value?

Comment: It doesn't. It creates a Guava `Function`, which is similar to a `Map`. The `Map` interface doesn't allow for default values.

Comment: Ok, I thought that there was a leap of logic somewhere that I wasn't getting.  The OP is asking specifically for an implementation of `Map`, and you say that this does "exactly what you want".

Comment: What the OP wants breaks `Map`'s contract, so the OP wants something that isn't a `Map`. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can simply write a wrapper function to get the value you want and if it's `null` return the default instead.

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();

public List<String> myGet(String key) {
    List<String> ret = myMap.get(key);
    if(ret == NULL) {
        return defaultList(); // where defaultList is a function that generates your default list.
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This assumes that your `myMap` is a global variable (for simplicity's sake), if that's not what you want then you can also extend `Map` or `HashMap` into something like `MyMap` and just include this extra function. That way you can use it from any place where a `MyMap`  object is instantiated.

Comment: This doesn't help much if you need to pass the map to something expecting a Map.