# HashMap get(Object) always returns String instead of other Object

Tags: java, jsf

Having an issue that is just stumping me. I have a HashMap declared to use a String as the Key and my own KWIKattribute as the Value.

```
private HashMap<String, KWIKattribute> attributes = new HashMap<String, KWIKattribute>();
```

I put objects into it, where sgml_xml_tag is a String and kattr is an instance of KWIKattribute.

```
attributes.put(sgml_xml_tag, kattr);
```

When I try to get the value back out as a KWIKattribute

```
for (Map.Entry<String, KWIKattribute> e : attributes.entrySet()) {
        String key = e.getKey();
        KWIKattribute kattr = (KWIKattribute) attributes.get(e.getKey());
}
```

an exception is thrown

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.northgrum.adt.kwik.model.KWIKattribute
```

I know this is probably a simple stupid error on my part somewhere, but I'm not seeing what it is. Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you use `e.getValue()`?

Comment: What version of JSF is it? It's realted to JSF `javax.faces.el.EvaluationException`. The code you have posted is not relevant I think. Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: The real question is why do you need to cast after the call to `attributes.get()`?  If it's doing what we all think, then that method should be returning a `KWIKattribute` reference anyway.  Is it possible that you're shadowing your declaration of `attributes` with another map in the local scope?

Comment: There is no other map in the scope. What I have included in my post is literally the only code (other than some debuggin println statements) that I have so far, since this project is just getting started.

Comment: But that's not where the exception occured. The stacktrace should help.

Comment: The full stack trace seems to be too large to post, but here's part of it: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.northgrum.adt.kwik.model.KWIKattribute at com.northgrum.adt.kwik.view.KWIKhandler.submit_action(KWIKhandler.java:291) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

Comment: @SharonBond did you ever discover a solution? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: @medley56, I'm sorry, but I'm on another project now and do not have access to that code. I'm sure that I did find a solution, but what it is, I can't remember. Good luck on your code!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
KWIKattribute kattr = (KWIKattribute) attributes.get(e.getKey());
```

use

```
KWIKattribute kattr = e.getValue();
```

You are iterating over the entry set of the map. Each entry contains a key and the value associated with that key in the map. You can get the value from the entry directly; it's not necessary to look it up in the map, as you are doing.

That said, it's strange that you get this error. First of all, the cast to `KWIKattribute` shouldn't be necessary at all. Second, if `attributes` is really a `HashMap<String, KWIKattribute>`, it's impossible that there are `String` objects stored in it as values.

Comment: The "impossibility" is what's stumping me. I started with e.getValue() and it too returned a String. If I do Object obj = e.getValue(), then I print the class of the Object, it's java.lang.String.

Comment: What happens if you remove the cast to `KWIKattribute`? Does it still compile, or do you get an error? If you get an error, then is `attributes` really a `HashMap<String, KWIKattribute>` or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

The `Map.Entry`-class, which you use to iterate over the entry-set of your Map has a [`getValue()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29), which returns the value to the current key.

Otherwise, if you're only interested in the values from the Map, you can also iterate over the [values-collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29):

```
for (KWIKattribute attr : attributes.values()){
  // Do your work with attr
}
```