# Accessing Kotlin extension functions from Java

Tags: java, kotlin, extension-function

Is it possible to access extension functions from Java code?

I defined the extension function in a Kotlin file.

```
package com.test.extensions

import com.test.model.MyModel

/**
 *
 */
public fun MyModel.bar(): Int {
    return this.name.length()
}
```

Where `MyModel` is a (generated) java class.
Now, I wanted to access it in my normal java code:

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();
model.bar();
```

However, that doesn't work. **The IDE won't recognize the `bar()` method and compilation fails.**

What does work is using with a static function from kotlin:

```
public fun bar(): Int {
   return 2*2
}
```

by using `import com.test.extensions.ExtensionsPackage` so my IDE seems to be configured correctly.

I searched through the whole Java-interop file from the kotlin docs and also googled a lot, but I couldn't find it.

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Comment: Please elaborate on *does not work*? Does it compile, throws an exception, or what? Also have you `import package com.test.extensions.MyModel`?

Comment: @meskobalazs also, I can't even import that. I can only import `com.test.extensions.ExtensionsPackage`

Answer (score 342, accepted):

All Kotlin functions declared in a file will be compiled by default to static methods in a class within the same package and with a name derived from the Kotlin source file (First letter capitalized and *".kt"* extension replaced with the *"Kt"* suffix). Methods generated for extension functions will have an additional first parameter with the extension function receiver type.

Applying it to the original question, Java compiler will see Kotlin source file with the name *example.kt*

```
package com.test.extensions

public fun MyModel.bar(): Int { /* actual code */ }
```

as if the following Java class was declared

```
package com.test.extensions

class ExampleKt {
    public static int bar(MyModel receiver) { /* actual code */ }
}
```

As nothing happens with the extended class from the Java point of view, you can't just use dot-syntax to access such methods. But they are still callable as normal Java static methods:

```
import com.test.extensions.ExampleKt;

MyModel model = new MyModel();
ExampleKt.bar(model);
```

Static import can be used for ExampleKt class:

```
import static com.test.extensions.ExampleKt.*;

MyModel model = new MyModel();
bar(model);
```

Comment: I understood, it means I can't use extension from Kotlin to Java unless I write static functions?

Comment: JFYI, You can also change the name of the class with @file:JvmName("<TheNameThatYouWant>Utils").

Comment: what if i create an extension with parameters?

Comment: @AmirG parameters will follow the instance. In this case it would be `bar(model, param1, param2);`

Answer (score 47):

Kotlin top-level extension function are compiled as Java static methods.

Given Kotlin file `Extensions.kt` in package `foo.bar` containing:

```
fun String.bar(): Int {
    ...
}
```

The equivalent Java code would be:

```
package foo.bar;

class ExtensionsKt {
    public static int bar(String receiver) { 
        ...
    }
}
```

Unless, that is, `Extensions.kt` contained the line

```
@file:JvmName("DemoUtils")
```

In which case the Java static class would be named `DemoUtils`

In Kotlin, extension methods can be declared in other ways. (For example, as a member function or as an extension of a companion object.)

Answer (score 26):

With newer **KotlinEx**, you can directly call extension in java

```
ExtensionFileName.foo(field1...)
```

Basically, what it does is, it makes the receiver as first arguement and other arguments remain being at the same place

So For eg.

You have extension(in file Extension.kt)

```
Context.showToast(message:String){ 
...
}
```

In Java, you call it as

```
ExtensionKt.showToast(context, message);
```

Comment: what is "KotlinEx"? Google search for that term returns basically nothing

Answer (score 15):

I have a Kotlin file called NumberFormatting.kt that has the following function

```
fun Double.formattedFuelAmountString(): String? {
    val format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()
    format.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    format.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    val string = format.format(this)
    return string
}
```

In java  I simple access it over the file **NumberFormattingKt** in the following way after the required import    `import ....extensions.NumberFormattingKt;`

```
String literString = NumberFormattingKt.formattedFuelAmountString(item.getAmount());
```

Answer (score 8):

You can always see the **actual** Java code which is getting generated from your Kotlin code by going to `Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode`, then clicking `Decompile`. This can help you tremendously. In your case the Java code will look like this if you have `MyModelExtensions.kt`

```
public final class MyModelExtensionsKt {
   public static final int bar(@NotNull MyModel $receiver) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($receiver, "$receiver");
      return $receiver.getName().length();
   }
}
```

you can improve over this by using `@JvmName` on the file containing `bar`:

```
@file:JvmName("MyModels")
package io.sspinc.datahub.transformation

public fun MyModel.bar(): Int {
    return this.name.length
}
```

and it will result in this code:

```
public final class MyModels {
   public static final int bar(@NotNull MyModel $receiver) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($receiver, "$receiver");
      return $receiver.getName().length();
   }
}
```

Using `MyModels` is in line with what Effective Java suggests for utility classes. You can also rename your method like this:

```
public fun MyModel.extractBar(): Int {
    return this.name.length
}
```

then from the Java side it will look idiomatic:

```
MyModels.extractBar(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

Kotlin
[image: kotlin]

Java code
[image]

My project is an old android project created with Java; now I created the first kotlin file and added String extensions
fun String.isNotNullOrEmpty(): Boolean {... }

and I could call it from java file using:
StringUtilsKt.isNotNullOrEmpty(thestring).

My kotlin file name is StringUtils

Answer (score -1):

The other answers here cover the case of calling an extension function located at the top level of a Kotlin package file.

However, my case was that I needed to call an Extension function located inside a Class. Specifically, I was dealing with an Object.

The solution is *incredibly simple*.

All you have to do is annotate your extension function as `@JvmStatic`, and voila! Your Java code will be able to access it and use it.

Comment: Why the downvote? My answer is correct and original.

Answer (score -2):

When you extend a class like this:

```
fun String.concatenatedLength(str: String): Int {
    return (this.length + str.length)
}

fun f() {
    var len = "one string".concatenatedLength("another string")
    println(len)
}
```

It will compile to this:

```
import kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public final class ExampleKt {
  public static final int concatenatedLength(@NotNull String $receiver, @NotNull String str) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull((Object) $receiver, (String) "$receiver");
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull((Object) str, (String) "str");
    return $receiver.length() + str.length();
  }

  public static final void f() {
    int len = ExampleKt.concatenatedLength("one string", "another string");
    System.out.println(len);
  }
}
```

There are more [examples here](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/yet-another-kotlin-vs-java-comparison).

Answer (score -4):

As far as I can tell this isn't possible. From my reading of the extensions docs, it appears that

```
public fun MyModel.bar(): Int {
    return this.name.length()
}
```

creates a new method with the signature

```
public static int MyModelBar(MyModel obj) {
    return obj.name.length();
}
```

Then, Kotlin maps that function to calls of the form `myModel.bar()`, where if `bar()` isn't found in the `MyModel` class it looks for static methods matching the signature and naming scheme it outputs. **Note that this is just an assumption from their statements about extensions being statically imported and not overriding defined methods. I haven't gotten far enough in their source to know for sure.**

So, assuming the above is true there's no way for Kotlin extensions to be called from plain old java code, as the compiler will just see an unknown method being called on an object and error out.

Comment: This answer is not correct, they can be accessed.  See accepted answer.

Comment: And the compiler isn't looking for static methods (especially not Java static methods). It's looking for extension methods that have been declared or imported in the same file.