# Thymeleaf does not recognize Kotlin Extension Functions defined in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

How can i use Kotlin extension function in a Thymeleaf template ?

For example, let's take a simple case

```html
    <div th:text="${mystring.test()}">placeholder</div>
```

where `test()` is an extension function for `String` class defined in a Spring Boot kotlin file as

```java
    fun String.test(): String = this
```

With this code I obtain a SpelEvaluationException

```
    org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: 
EL1004E: Method call: Method test() cannot be found on type java.lang.String
```

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf version is 2.1.1.RELEASE

Thank you

Comment: First guess is: you can't. Kotlin extension functions are scoped in the Kotlin scope, as soon as it is compiled in bytecode, this does not really exist, so the "Java world" cannot use a Kotlin extension function. I'm going to check it and if I get concrete proofs, I'm going to post you an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Kotlin extension functions from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294509/accessing-kotlin-extension-functions-from-java) I think you should find the proper explanation here.

Comment: I guessed it too, but I would have liked if it had been possible declare some dedicated method for the 'view side' of application. If you post your first comment as an answer, i'll accept it. Thank you

Comment: Just hit this problem..... wish it was ;)