# How to use an infix function of a Kotlin class in Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

Let us say that I have a class in Kotlin like below

Also, let us define an **infix** function ***generateEmailWithDomain*** which generates the email address based on the name with the given domain

```
class Person(var name: String) {}


infix fun Person.generateEmailWithDomain(domain: String): String = "${this.name}@$domain.com"
```

Now, as it is said that Kotlin is 100% interoperable with Java, how can I make use of this infix function in a JAVA class?

The above usage of infix may be inappropriate but I would like to know how this can be used in Java.

Please correct my understanding if it is wrong.

Comment: Yes, you can. An extension function, whether it's infix or not, is compiled to a static method of a class. You call that static method in Java. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions

Comment: Java doesn't care whether a function is marked as infix.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the docs (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation), `infix` seems to be mere syntactic sugar to me, as even the example there shows two ways of calling such function:

```
class MyStringCollection {
    infix fun add(s: String) { /*...*/ }

    fun build() {
        this add "abc"   // Correct
        add("abc")       // Correct
        //add "abc"        // Incorrect: the receiver must be specified
    }
}
```

So, from Java I would simply use the second one, tailored to your case that would be

```
String result = somePerson.generateEmailWithDomain(someString);
```

(as defining an extension function "outside" as `Person.generateEmailWithDomain()` is also just an optional possibility, when calling that will be a method of an actual `Person` object)

---

Ok, I was too optimistic. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/28364983/7916438, I would expect you to face a `static` method then, with two arguments, the first being the receiver, and the second one is the actual argument.

```
String result = Person.generateEmailWithDomain(somePerson, someString);
```

Comment: Please note that the infix function in my case is outside the class. If it was inside, I know that it can be used like you mentioned. So, whatever you mentioned won't work in my case

Comment: @dileepkumarjami added a new idea to try.

Comment: I think that's the only work around. Thanks for your time.