# Unable to access Kotlin Extension function from Java in case it has a lambda as its parameter

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Kotlin Global Function:

```
fun Activity.showWarningDialog(title: Int, description: Int,done:()->Unit) {  
   done()
}
```

calling this in java:

```
showWarningDialog(this,R.string.alert,R.string.leave_without_saving,() -> {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                finish();
            });
```

it gives the following error:
Cannot resolve method 'showWarningDialog(com.us.stickermaker.backgroundRemover.CutOutActivity, int, int, <lambda expression>)'

the function is imported into the activity file, works fine if we remove the lambda parameter.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something about how Kotlin methods are compiled, but your Kotlin method has 3 parameters, you're passing 4 parameters in your Java call

Comment: look closely, when a kotlin extension function is called in java, the "object" would be passed as a parameter in this case its an activity.

Comment: I see. I did a bit of reading on the subject, and from what I've read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28364983/8819761), you would need to prefix your method with the the filename it was declared in.

Comment: As i told in the question, if i remove the lambda, it works fine in java, and yes function is imported with the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda's type in Kotlin is `()->Unit`, which Java sees as `kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>`. So your Java lambda needs to return `Unit` instead of `void` as it currently does.

```java
showWarningDialog(this, R.string.alert, R.string.leave_without_saving, () -> {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                finish();
                return Unit.INSTANCE;
            });
```

should work. The Kotlin compiler inserts returning `Unit` for you, but Java doesn't treat `Unit` specially in any way.

If you just want to call the function from Java in one or a few places, this may be good enough; otherwise the way to make it convenient to call from Java is `fun interface` as shown in Andrii Hridin's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of lambda try to use "fun interface". For example:

```
fun interface OnWarningDoneListener {
    fun onWarningDone()
}

fun Activity.showWarningDialog(title: Int, description: Int, onWarningDoneListener: OnWarningDoneListener) {  
   onWarningDoneListener.onWarningDone()
}
```

Comment: Usama Saeed US, did you try this solution? I checked in my project and I have the successful result

Comment: in java we do thing with interfaces, but that time as passed and we want thing to be clean and easy using lambda.

Comment: `fun interface` is not simple `interface`.  It is special interface for lambda. Try to use

Comment: Is this solution works for you? Provide feedback please

Comment: I do not want to declare any interface separately, that is why  lambda.

Comment: What this answer doesn't explicitly say is that if you add the `fun interface` and change the parameter type, _calls_ to it use the same lambdas you have (in Java and Kotlin). Documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html