# How to create extention Function in java just like kotlin

Tags: java, methods, extension-methods

In my knowledge I don't think Java has Extension function such as kotlin . But i want to know is there any way have  to Extended String  class to create Extension function in java .

Comment: Sort answer: no.

Comment: Not short, but [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294509/accessing-kotlin-extension-functions-from-java)

Comment: `String` is a `final` class in Java that can not be extended. But you can define a utility-class with static methods there that operate on a String argument. Like in Apache's [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

Comment: Java does not support extension methods. Please take a look at [Java equivalent to C# extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359979/java-equivalent-to-c-sharp-extension-methods) for alternatives

Answer (score 1):

## The Extension Manifold

Java itself does not support extension methods, so external libraries come to rescue. **Manifold**

With Manifold you can create an Extension Class:

```
@Extension
public class MyStringExtension {
  public static void echo(@This String thiz) {
    System.out.println(thiz);
  }
}
```

Here we’ve added a new `echo()` method to `String`, so we use it like this:

```
"Java".echo();
```

Reference: http://manifold.systems/docs.html#the-extension-manifold

Comment: Maybe it is just the firewall setup in my workplace, but when I click that link, it is already dead?!

Comment: @GhostCat the link is alive, however it is not HTTPS