# Is it possible to create a Map where every Key points to the same Value?

Tags: java, hashtable

Is it possible (In Java) to create a Map where, no matter what key I was to search for, I would retrieve the same value? We can assume either a finite or infinite amount of keys.

I considered a map of size 1 and load factor of 1.0, with that value stored in it, but I'm nearly positive that the hashmap implementation will recognize the collision, and return null anyway.

I also entertained the possibility that if I created my own hashfunction for a variable, or even a new datatype that implemented Map, that I should be able to do this, but it may be a little messy. Perhaps not?

Of course, simply mapping the value to every single key would be very inefficient (unless there is a built in method for this, that I overlooked), and nowhere near as entertaining as hearing SO's answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose the most reasonable way to do this with existing API is like the following:

```
// Java 6/7
new TreeMap<K, V>(new Comparator<K>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(K lhs, K rhs) {
        return 0;
    }
});

// Java 8+
new TreeMap<K, V>((a, b) -> 0);
```

This [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) considers all keys equal but will otherwise maintain pretty good Map semantics.

Note that the first key you put in the Map will stay in it forever unless you `remove` it.

i.e.

```
m.put("abc", "123");
m.put("def", "456");
// prints something like {abc=456}
System.out.println(m);
```

So you might keep that in mind for example if you planned on examining the `entrySet`.

Comment: Creative answer! I didn't think of a comparator, as I've never had to use one in practice before. I'll try this out, thanks.

Comment: TreeMap with a custom Comparator can do lots of interesting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure on what you're trying to accomplish here but all you need to do is **implement** [**Map**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). An example:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class ImmutableMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    private final V immutableValue;

    public ImmutableMap(final V immutableValue) {
        this.immutableValue = immutableValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        if (value == immutableValue)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return immutableValue;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * Below are some unnecessary methods for the purpose of this class.
     * You may decide their action.
     */

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this was what I was considering. It just seemed like a less than ideal situation, since it creates a class that will only be used once.

Comment: You should implement Map instead of HashMap and implement all methods correctly.

Comment: I am not able to understand that `immutableValue` is not mapped to any key, and `put` function is not available. So it is similar to normal `dto` which can hold the same data without extending to HashMap. Please correct me if I am going wrong anywhere in my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, I guess Map with default value should work for you. This is pretty standard pattern.

1. You can either use apache commons [DefaultedMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/DefaultedMap.html) implementation
2. In Java 8, you can use Map.getOrDefault
3. You can always implement your own

[HashMap to return default value for non-found keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519339/hashmap-to-return-default-value-for-non-found-keys)