# Loading map with keys that are not present, else load default

Tags: java, dictionary

Here is an example method:

```
public void loadStuff(Map<String, Object> someMap) {
  Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  //I now load defaults here first
  myMap.put("One", someObject);
  myMap.put("two", someObject);
  myMap.put("three", someObject);

  //Now I put the entire someMap so that only those keys that are present in someMap are overridden in myMap and others remain default.
  myMap.putAll(someMap);
}
```

Now, is there a better way of doing these redundant puts as the number of defaults in my scenario are a lot.

Comment: This looks quite straightforward, I think it's not all that bad;  btw in your example `default` is a Java reserved keyword, use something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider creating an initial map with your defaults in, and then use:

```
// Alternatively, you could use clone()
Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(defaults);
myMap.putAll(someMap);
```

Aside from anything else that means you can load the "default map" from a properties file or whatever.

If you really don't like the fact that it will put each value twice, you could write a loop to check for each key - but I'd personally just use the above code. It's simple and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to preload a single answer for just a few items, or are you wanting a default for all unfound keys? If you want to change the default answer from `null` to something else, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833336/map-implementation-that-allows-a-default-vaue-from-a-java-map-instead-of-null). If you're wanting to preload some items, then you'll need to `put` all of them, though it's best not to embed the values in code like that; use a `for` loop instead that iterates over a single official list of the keys.

If you are going to be initializing blank copies of this `Map` frequently, it will make more sense to have a template `Map` that each `myMap` [is constructed from](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28java.util.Map%29); either a `HashMap` wrapped as unmodifiable or a Guava `ImmutableMap` are good choices there. Constructing from a preexisting `Map` instead of copying all of the elements into the new `HashMap` is much more efficient since the new one knows how big to make itself.